# Unsplash API Question on JSON to Display in HTML

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am unable to get the fetched JSON data to display in the HTML webpage. The data comes in fine, but I am unable to get it to display. Must be some issue with how I am bringing in the objects and the arrays.

Please assist.

```
const API_URL = 'https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=1&client_id=00000000000';
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const input = document.querySelector('input');

const loadingImage = document.querySelector('#loadingImage');
const imageSection = document.querySelector('.image');

loadingImage.style.display = 'none';

form.addEventListener('submit', formSubmitted);

function formSubmitted(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const searchTerm = input.value;

    searchStart();
    search(searchTerm)
        .then(displayImages)
        .then(() => {
            loadingImage.style.display = 'none';
        });
}

function searchStart() {
    loadingImage.style.display = '';
    imageSection.innerHTML = '';
}

function search(searchTerm) {
    const url = `${API_URL}&query=${searchTerm}`;
    loadingImage.style.display ='';
    return fetch(url)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        });
}


 function displayImages (images) {
      images.forEach(results => {
          const imageElement = document.createElement('img');
          imageElement.src = results[0].urls.full;
          imageSection.appendChild(imageElement);
      });
  }
```

Example response

```
{
  "total": 8083,
  "total_pages": 809,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "qY9zgRqmNtA",
      "created_at": "2018-03-27T11:42:54-04:00",
      "updated_at": "2018-08-28T20:56:16-04:00",
      "width": 6435,
      "height": 4290,
      "color": "#FCFDFD",
      "description": "people working inside white and black room",
      "urls": {
        "raw": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522165078649-823cf4dbaf46?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjM4NDEyfQ&s=7d8696c868ca2cea4d2b337d0f42f6c1",
```

Comment: The data in the JSON for unsplash is stored  like : data.results[0].urls.full . Essentially would like to get the url data to populate in a section element in the html file.

Comment: `The data comes in fine` how do you know? any errors in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: images.forEach is not a function
    at displayImages (main.js:40)
displayImages @ main.js:40
Promise.then (async)
formSubmitted @ main.js:19

Comment: well, there you go ... images isn't an **Array** - only you can see what the API returns, clearly the "top" level object in the returned JSON is not an Array - I recommend you `console.log(images)` in `displayImages` to see what you are receiving and adjust your code appropriately

Comment: {
  "total": 8083,
  "total_pages": 809,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "qY9zgRqmNtA",
      "created_at": "2018-03-27T11:42:54-04:00",
      "updated_at": "2018-08-28T20:56:16-04:00",
      "width": 6435,
      "height": 4290,
      "color": "#FCFDFD",
      "description": "people working inside white and black room",
      "urls": {
        "raw": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522165078649-823cf4dbaf46?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjM4NDEyfQ&s=7d8696c868ca2cea4d2b337d0f42f6c1",

Comment: well, clearly not an array, but I can't read that - perhaps format it nicely in the **question**

Comment: "results" is the array. Inside it, is the object "urls" and then the link is in the object "full"

Comment: so it's `images.results.forEach(img => imageElement.src = img.full;`

Comment: {
      "total": 8083,
      "total_pages": 809,
      "results": [
        {
          "id": "qY9zgRqmNtA",
          "created_at": "2018-03-27T11:42:54-04:00",
          "updated_at": "2018-08-28T20:56:16-04:00",
          "width": 6435,
          "height": 4290,
          "color": "#FCFDFD",
          "description": "people working inside white and black room",
          "urls": {
           "raw": "link",

Comment: why did you jsut post that again as a **comment**? edit your question :p

Comment: Yes. I am unable to grab the code in the answers properly

Comment: so, you cant' edit your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the format of the resulting data, you need to change displayImages as follows

While I can't see that each entry has a property called `full` I am assuming it from the original code - it would be easier if a proper example of data was put in the question itself

```
 function displayImages (result) {
      result.results.forEach(img=> {
          const imageElement = document.createElement('img');
          imageElement.src = img.urls.full; // does full exist?
          imageSection.appendChild(imageElement);
      });
  }
```

Comment: I've added the JSON data. When I add this snippet of code, I get -----GET http://127.0.0.1:54652/undefined 404 (Not Found)
Image (async)
result.results.forEach.img @ main.js:42
displayImages @ main.js:40
Promise.then (async)
formSubmitted @ main.js:18

Comment: oh, I see ... because your original code had a property called **full** which simply doesn't exist (is undefined) - let me fix my answer based on what you now say is the response

Comment: if there is a `full` in the `urls` object, then you can use that

Comment: Viola! It Worked. Thanks a ton! :) :)

Comment: having the received data helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "total": 8083,
  "total_pages": 809,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "qY9zgRqmNtA",
      "created_at": "2018-03-27T11:42:54-04:00",
      "updated_at": "2018-08-28T20:56:16-04:00",
      "width": 6435,
      "height": 4290,
      "color": "#FCFDFD",
      "description": "people working inside white and black room",
      "urls": {
        "raw": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522165078649-823cf4dbaf46?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjM4NDEyfQ&s=7d8696c868ca2cea4d2b337d0f42f6c1",
```

Comment: I've put this in the question for you - note, there is no `full` property in `urls` - perhaps you've cut short the example